# Iterative formula for finding prime numbers in java

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, formulas

I cannot get my code to work for the life of me. I have been fighting with it for the past 13 hours. I am supposed to use a function GetPrime, which is an array, to call a boolean function IsPrime to look up all numbers and return the ones that are prime. We can use either iterative or recursive formulas, but it is suggested that we use iterative. This is the code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class util3_2 {


public static boolean IsPrime(int p) {

if (p % 2 == 0) return false;

for(int i = 3; i * i <= p; i += 2) {
    if(p % i == 0)
    return false;
}
return true;
}  

public static int[] GetPrimes(int n)   {

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i ++)
{
   int[] array = new int [n];

    IsPrime(n);

}
```

We are using java. Some of the functions are giving me a very hard time, not to mention, it does not want brackets at the end, like a baby fighting to keep food out of his or her mouth. I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: You are missing two brackets at the end. `GetPrimes` is missing a return statement. Your code doesn't follow java naming conventions. Your code isn't properly formatted. You never use what is returned by `IsPrime(n)`.

Comment: I think, your code is incomplete. If this is your whole code, then surely it will  not run.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the missing bracket, i think you got the algorithm off. consider your `for` loop on your `IsPrime` (which is also named incorrectly, should be `isPrime`):

```
for(int i = 2; i * i <= p; i += 2) {
    if(p % i == 0)
    return false;
}
```

A prime number is only divisible by one and itself. so you should test it until you reach the number, like so:

```
for(int i = 3; i != p ; i++) {

    if(p % i == 0){
      return false;
     }

}
```

It would be a good practice to use braces on your `if`s even though it comprises a single line of code inside.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array in each iteration of the loop. And then you discard that array object, and also never use the value returned by IsPrime().

Use this code snippet. Here you are passing an array of numbers to getPrimes, which after computation will return array of Integers containing only Prime numbers, which used your IsPrime().

```
public static Integer[] getPrimes(int[] arrayOfNums){
    List<Integer> primes;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arrayOfNums.length; i++) {
        if(IsPrime(arrayOfNums[i])){
            primes.add(arrayOfNums[i]);
        }
    }

    return primes.toArray(new Integer[arrayOfNums.length]);
}
```